# Define collection of data class

Tags: kotlin

If I've the below data class

```
data class User(val name: String = "", val age: Int = 0)
```

How can I define a collection of it, like:

```
var user = User [] // this is not working
```

I need to be able to call the users by:

```
user[0].name // something like this!
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I read it but could not understand how to use it with `data class`

Comment: there is no difference to a normal class -> e.g. `MutableList<User>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Defining a List collection in Kotlin in different ways:

- **Immutable variable with immutable (read only) list:**

  ```
  val users: List<User> = listOf( User("Tom", 32), User("John", 64) )
  ```
- **Immutable variable with mutable list:**

  ```
  val users: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf( User("Tom", 32), User("John", 64) )
  ```

  or without initial value - empty list and without explicit variable type:

  ```
  val users = mutableListOf<User>()
  //or
  val users = ArrayList<User>()
  ```

  - you can add items to list:

    - `users.add(anohterUser)` or
    - `users += anotherUser` (under the hood it's `users.add(anohterUser)`)

- **Mutable variable with immutable list:**

  ```
  var users: List<User> = listOf( User("Tom", 32), User("John", 64) )
  ```

  or without initial value - empty list and without explicit variable type:

  ```
  var users = emptyList<User>()
  ```

  - NOTE: you can add* items to list:

    - `users += anotherUser` - *it creates new ArrayList and assigns it to `users`

- **Mutable variable with mutable list:**

  ```
  var users: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf( User("Tom", 32), User("John", 64) )
  ```

  or without initial value - empty list and without explicit variable type:

  ```
  var users = emptyList<User>().toMutableList()
  //or
  var users = ArrayList<User>()
  ```

  - NOTE: you can add items to list:

    - `users.add(anohterUser)`
    - but not using `users += anotherUser`

      > Error: Kotlin: Assignment operators ambiguity: 
      >   public operator fun  Collection.plus(element: String): List defined in kotlin.collections 
      >   @InlineOnly public inline operator fun  MutableCollection.plusAssign(element: String): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

see also:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Comment: What if my initial values are unknown, is `var supply = ArrayList<transaction>()` fine?

Comment: @HasanAYousef yes. (`var supply = ArrayList<Transaction>()`)

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this in Kotlin:

```
val array = arrayOf(User("name1"), User("name2"))
```

If you want to create an Array without adding elements right away, use

```
val arrayList = ArrayList<User>()
```

In this case you have to specify the element type explicitely because there is nothing to infer it from.

From the [ArrayList docu](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html):

> Povides a MutableList implementation, which uses a 
>   resizable array as its backing storage